# Certbot 0.34.2 acme-challenge dns fails on Mac OS X 12.0.1 after clone data/ update to a new machine (came from OS X 10.15.7 Catalina)

Tags: apache

I recently had to change my Mac machine (OS X 10.15.7 / Intel) to a bigger machine (OS X 12.0.1 / Intel). There I'm running a tomcat 9.0.39

As I wanted to renew the certificate it didn't work, it says:

Terminal:

```
admin24@toolskript ~ % sudo certbot certonly -a manual -d toolskript.mydomain.com --preferred-challenges dns
Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/certbot", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3191, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3175, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3204, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'certbot==0.34.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

/cellar [image]

Does anyone has an idea what's going wrong or had the same issue? I have not found a compatibility list which Certbot version supports which OS X. Is 0.34.2 just ok for OS X 12.0.1? It was originally set up with home-brew. Now brew is:

Homebrew 3.1.3-dirty Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 65e5a0ea75; last commit 2021-04-21)

What is best for updating - if needed? First uninstall the current? Do I loose all settings/ dependencies when installing a newer version?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please paste your terminal output in code tags. As a picture that small it's unreadable, and also unsearchable by anyone else with the same question. Also, what purpose is the Finder screenshot providing?

Comment: 12.0.1 was horribly buggy. Current is 12.6.1

Comment: System updated to 12.6.1 - but still the same problems